# Correct configuration of nginx for rewrite and access control

Tags: nginx, access-control, rewrite

Here is my current nginx config

```
server_name  web.com;
server_tokens off;

root /usr/share/nginx/html/web;
index index.php;   

if ( $request_uri ~ "/index.(php|html?)" ) {
rewrite ^ /$1 permanent;
}

location / {   
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404; 
}

error_page   404              /404.html;
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}


location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}   

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files  $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

What I'm trying to do:

1. `web.com?page=somepage&other_arg=arg&..` rewrite to `web.com/somepage/arg/...`.

My methods didn't work, sometimes giving errors: `failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream` or `accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)`

2. Allow direct access via browser URL only to index.php in root folder. Other files and directories can't be accessed via browser (but can through GET,POST, etc)

I used `internal` directive, worked as expected, however I couldn't set exception for index.php

Could anyone suggest an optimal method of doing that?